# How do I count an occurence of a specific word in a txt file in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to just create a basic word counter for a specific word inside the "list.txt" document. The code I'm using right now is not scanning "Customer" even though Customer appears a few times in the word document already, I've tried making a String variable with the value of "Customer" instead but that also didn't work, could anyone perhaps correct where I've gone wrong?

```
static int totalContracts() throws FileNotFoundException 
{
    Scanner scannerInput = new Scanner("list.txt");
    int count = 0;
    while (scannerInput.hasNext()) 
    { 
        String nextWord = scannerInput.next();
        System.out.println(nextWord);
        if (nextWord.equals("Customer")) 
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed a parameter of type String to the Scanner in which the Scanner would only produce values from that specified String.

In order for the scanner to produce values from an actual file, you can pass in a File object defining the path to the file.

To do this, you should initialize a new File object and pass it the path to the file you're trying to scan. Once you do this you can then pass the File object to the Scanner.

```
File file_to_scan = new File("list.txt");
Scanner scanner_input = new Scanner(file_to_scan);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Matt, I'm new to this so I've obviously made a silly mistake, appreciate it!

Comment: No worries! You'll get the hang of things quickly!

Comment: Just a quick question Matt if you don't mind, in my Java it keeps outputting the whole txt document, then the word count below it, I only want to output the count when I press run, not the whole txt document, anyway to change that?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it seems you're printing the next word during each iteration which would print the whole text document. In order to fix that you would just need to remove that print line.

As for outputting the count, you'll use the same print method that you used before, but you want to pass it the value to print which would be "count." In addition, you should also print it after the while loop so it is only executed once instead of each iteration.

Answer (score 3):

You did not open the file.

```
Scanner scannerInput = new Scanner(new File("list.txt"));
```

If you use `new Scanner("list.txt")` it just scan the text "list.txt".

Comment: Thank you Zhh, both answers worked well, appreciate this!